# Speechmike pro drivers

Tags: drivers, proprietary-drivers

**UPDATE 1:**

```
oshiro@laptop:~$ lsusb -vt
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 4, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 5, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 6, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Anyone know if proprietary or even non proprietary drivers exist to get the Philips speech-mike pro lfh3200/15 to work on Linux fully?

The device partially works out of the box.  I.e. it functions as a mouse and the devices built-in speaker works, but I can't seem to dictate with it.  It's not being recognized as a dictation device out of the box.

The OS I am using is Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: "Fully"- do you have a driver now that provides some functions but not others, or are you just looking for any driver at all?

Comment: If I plug it into a computer running Linux, it works as a mouse and the speaker works, but I can't seem to dictate with it.  It's not being recognized as a dictation device out of the box.

Comment: `lsusb -vt` would be a starter.

Comment: @JodkaLemon, updated original question with details.

Comment: what gives `alsa -l'?

Comment: @JodkaLemon, what is the actual command?  When I try `alsa -l`, it just gives me usage instructions, and I see no `-l` in the instructions.

Comment: Sorry, that was bs. Wasn't focused. You could start `alsamixer` and see whether the mic appears and is maybe muted. Otherwise test `alsactl init`.